# Python "Guess The Number" game giving unexpected results

Tags: python

i recently started learning python and my friend from work who is a programmer gave me a simple challenge to write a "guess the number" style game.

So i came up with something as follows:

```
import random

print("Hello, welcome to GUESS THE NUMBER game")

run = True


def again():
    global run
    playagain = str(input("Would you like to play again? Type y/n for yes or no: "))
    if playagain == "y":
        run = True
    elif playagain == "n":
        run = False


while run:

    guess = int(input("Guess the number between 1 and 10: "))
    num1 = random.randint(1, 10)

    if guess == num1:
        print("CONGRATULATIONS, YOU HAVE GUESSED THE NUMBER, THE ANSWER WAS " + str(num1))
        again()
    elif guess > num1:
        print("Too high, go lower!")
    elif guess < num1:
        print("Too small, go higher!")
```

My problem is that after the user has chosen to play again, the numbers sometimes dont register and go out of whack. For example you input 5 and it says too low, but if you input 6 it says too high! I don't seem to be dealing in float numbers so they should be whole, any ideas where i went wrong?

Thanks in advance and very excited to learn more on the subject

Comment: You are generating a new random number in your loop, so after every turn, it changes. Try generating `num1` before

Comment: try to debug your code... you can add print statements to print out the variable values, so you can understand your code flow

Comment: This isn't a bug, it's just hard mode. Once someone's gotten so good at "guess the number" that they can always solve it in log N turns, spring this on them and suddenly they're taking average N turns (and worst case infinite), which is much more of a challenge. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're regenerating the random number every time.

```
num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
```

Instead, maybe put the guess and check logic inside it's own loop.

```
while True:
    guess = int(input("Guess the number between 1 and 10: "))

    if guess == num1:
        print("CONGRATULATIONS, YOU HAVE GUESSED THE NUMBER, THE ANSWER WAS " + str(num1))
        break # leave the while True loop
    elif guess > num1:
        print("Too high, go lower!")
    elif guess < num1:
        print("Too small, go higher!")

again()
```

Comment: Oh god i feel so stupid, seems like such an obvious mistake. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

You are calculating the random number on each iteration of the loop. Therefore every time you guess the random number changes.

import random

```
print("Hello, welcome to GUESS THE NUMBER game")

run = True


def again():
    global run
    playagain = str(input("Would you like to play again? Type y/n for yes or no: "))
if playagain == "y":
    run = True
elif playagain == "n":
    run = False

num1 = random.randint(1, 10)

while run:

    guess = int(input("Guess the number between 1 and 10: "))

    if guess == num1:
        print("CONGRATULATIONS, YOU HAVE GUESSED THE NUMBER, THE ANSWER WAS " + str(num1))
        again()
    elif guess > num1:
        print("Too high, go lower!")
    elif guess < num1:
        print("Too small, go higher!")
```

Comment: Wouldnt this mean that in the same instance of the game, unless i restarted, the num1 will always be the same? I think my attempt was to reGenerate a new random number when player pressed "y" to play again thats why i put it there, it worked but a bit too well by generating a new number on each guess lol

Comment: @Max Yes—but you can fix that with another loop. The outer loop runs once for each game, and the inner loop (the one from this answer) runs once for each guess within a game.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you for the advice, i'll give that a try

Comment: @Max You might want to try turning this into a function, so you don't end up with too many levels of indentation and confusion on what happens when you `break` out of a loop.